# Run application with Docker dependent on a jar library on github

Tags: java, maven, docker

I created a library that is now on github. 
This library use maven for building.

Now, i want to create an app dependent on this library (generates by mvn package). 
So every time i will create my Docker Image, i want the last version of the Jar that the source code is on github for my app (doing the mvn package each time).

Is it possible to do it with dockers? How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. In your docker file install git. Ex. for alpine linux do 
   `RUN apk update
   RUN apk add git`
2. Install java. `RUN apk add openjdk8`
3. Install wget. `RUN apk add wget`
4. Install maven in your docker image. 
   `RUN wget http://mirror.reverse.net/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.5.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.3-bin.tar.gz
   RUN tar -zxvf apache-maven-3.5.3-bin.tar.gz`
5. Clone your repository `RUN git clone myrepourl`
6. Build with maven `RUN cd /myrepo && /apache-maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn clean install`
7. Copy the jar where ever you need it with `RUN /apache-maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn dependency:copy`. See details about how to use `dendency:copy` here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html
8. Do any other setup you need for your app in your docker image.